# Output of lsusb -v for GoPro / Sony AS-30

Tags: linux, usb, udev, gopro

Someone here who has Linux knowledge and a GoPro / Sony Action camera (like AS-30) who can help me with the output of running `lsusb` with the camera connected via USB to the computer:

```
lsusb -d <idVendor>:<idProduct> -v
```

I am interested just in the Device Descriptor “iSerial” field:

```
Example output:
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               1.10
  bDeviceClass          239 Miscellaneous Device
  bDeviceSubClass         2 ?
  bDeviceProtocol         1 Interface Association
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x0402 ALi Corp.
  idProduct          0x9665 Gateway Webcam
  bcdDevice            0.09
  iManufacturer           3 
  iProduct                1 
  iSerial                 0  <-- Some manufactures make this unique for every device/some don't include it
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
```

My config will have multiple identical cameras connected to the same computer, and I want to know if I can use the “iSerial” number to uniquely identify each camera.
I am not interested in receiving an “iSerial” number, just if you can confirm that this number looks unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have run `lsusb -v` for my USB-connected GoPro Hero 4 Silver. The returned `iSerial` indeed *looks* like a (unique) serial number. The returned number is composed of a single capital letter followed by 13 digits.

<del>Unfortunately, I don’t have multiple GoPro cameras to confirm that they actually all return different numbers.</del> I neither have a Sony AS-30 to check there.

**EDITED** to add: I have just found the same serial number returned by `lsusb` on a sticker in the battery case of the camera. So it indeed seems to be a unique serial number.